# How to get the generated id from an inserted row using ExecuteScalar?

Tags: c#, oracle, ado.net

I know that in **Oracle** I can get the generated id (or any other column) from an inserted row as an output parameter.
Ex:

```
insert into foo values('foo','bar') returning id into :myOutputParameter
```

Is there a way to do the same, but using ExecuteScalar instead of ExecuteNonQuery?

I don't want to use output parameters or stored procedures.

ps: I'm using **Oracle**, not sql server!!!

Comment: Putting this as a comment as it's speculative, but Sql Server ha "@@SCOPE_IDENTITY" so the statement can be "insert into fo....; select @@SCOPE_IDENTITY" ... Does Oracle have something similar?

Comment: As For SQL Server, I don't know about this system variable @@SCOPE_IDENTITY, thus I know about an IDENT_CURRENT scalar function which does the same (SELECT IDENT_CURRENT(N'TableName')

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Oracle uses sequences as for his identity columns, if we may say so.

If you have set a sequence for your table primary key, you also have to write a trigger that will insert the Sequence.NextValue or so into your primary key field.

Assuming that you are already familiar with this concept, simply query your sequence, then you will get your answer. What is very practiced in Oracle is to make yourself a function which will return an INT, then within your function, you perform your INSERT. Assuming that you have setup your trigger correctly, you will then be able to return the value of your sequence by querying it.

Here's an instance:

```
CREATE TABLE my_table (
    id_my_table INT PRIMARY KEY
    description VARCHAR2(100) NOT NULL
)

CREATE SEQUENCE my_table_seq
   MINVALUE 1
   MAXVALUE 1000
   START WITH 1
   INCREMENT BY 2
   CACHE 5;
```

If you want to manage the auto-increment yourself, here's how:

```
INSERT INTO my_table (
    id_my_table,
    description
) VALUES (my_table_seq.NEXTVAL, "Some description");
COMMIT;
```

On the other hand, if you wish not to care about the PRIMARY KEY increment, you may proceed with a trigger.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER my_table_insert_trg
    BEFORE INSERT ON my_table FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    SELECT my_table_seq.NEXTVAL INTO :NEW.id_my_table FROM DUAL;
END;
```

Then, when you're inserting, you simply type the INSERT statement as follows:

```
INSERT INTO my_table (description) VALUES ("Some other description");
COMMIT;
```

After an INSERT, I guess you'll want to

```
SELECT my_table_seq.CURRVAL
```

or something like this to select the actual value of your sequence.

Here are some links to help:

http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Sequence

http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/AutoNumber_and_Identity_columns

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi Will,
Nice, I didn't think about seq.CURRVAL. But is this save? I mean, if someone inserts a row between my two calls (insert, select)?

Comment: Typically these kinds of operations are relative to your database connection/session to prevent just such an occurrence.  I can't find it in black & white for Oracle but that's the way it works for MySQL, Access, SQL Server, etc.

Comment: Oracle will perform the inserts in a sequential manner. Once it got through the first INSERT statement and returned the new current sequence's value, it will perform the other insert.

As stated by Mr. Crazy Joe Malloy, that is no matter what the way of doing it anyway. :)

We must not forget that Oracle works in a transactional way. So, no NEXTVALUE will be selected from the sequence as long as the INSERT statement is not COMMITed.

In anyway, if I remember correctly, there's somekind of lock somewhere (TABLE or SEQUENCE) while performing the transaction.

Comment: The seq.CURRVAL is a session value for your distinct oracle session.  It will only be changed by your doing another seq.NEXTVAL. Another's reference of seq.NEXTVAL will not affect your seq.CURRVAL.

Comment: Only a small point but ... I think "SELECT my_table_seq.CURRVAL" should be "SELECT my_table_seq.CURRVAL from DUAL"

Answer (score 31):

If you are on oracle, you have to use ExecuteNonQuery and ResultParameter. There is no way to write this as query.

```
using (OracleCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand()) {
    cmd.CommandText = "insert into foo values('foo','bar') returning id into :myOutputParameter";
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("myOutputParameter", OracleDbType.Decimal), ParameterDirection.ReturnValue);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); // an INSERT is always a Non Query
    return Convert.ToDecimal(cmd.Parameters["myOutputParameter"].Value);
}
```

Comment: What is the difference between `ParameterDirection.ReturnValue` and `ParameterDirection.Output` ?

Comment: ParameterDirection.ReturnValue is the result of a function. ParameterDirection.Output is for parameters in methods (functions or procedures) which are defined as out or inout.

Comment: Sigh!  I keep getting `ORA-12537: Network Session: End of file` at ExecuteNonQuery no matter what I try :(

Comment: It returns `ORA-12537: Network Session: End of file` error if using `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client` but works normally with `System.Data.OracleClient`

Comment: Does someone know if there is a bug in current .net oracle data access component?

Comment: I was getting ORA-12537: Network Session: End of file with ParameterDirection.Output. I tried ParameterDirection.ReturnValue and it worked.

Answer (score 4):

You can use below code.

```
    using (OracleCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
    {
        cmd.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO my_table(name, address)
            VALUES ('Girish','Gurgaon India')
            RETURNING my_id INTO :my_id_param";
        OracleParameter outputParameter = new OracleParameter("my_id_param", OracleDbType.Decimal);
        outputParameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(outputParameter);        
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();        
        return Convert.ToDecimal(outputParameter.Value);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

one possible way if one can add one column named "guid" to the table :
when inserting one record from c#, generate a guid and write it to the guid column.
then perform a select with the generated guid, and you have got the id of inserted record :)

Answer (score 0):

```
Select  t.userid_pk From Crm_User_Info T
Where T.Rowid = (select max(t.rowid) from crm_user_info t)
```

this will return your required id