# What is the correct way to get created row Id on Oracle using the RETURNING INTO clause in c# and OCI:

Tags: c#, sql, oracle

I have the following statement to insert row and get the Id or row inserted:

```
    int returnId;
    string sql = "INSERT INTO table_name (a, b, c) VALUES (1, 2, 3) RETURNING ID INTO :returnId;";

    OracleCommand command = conn.CreateCommand();
    command.CommandText = sql;

    Console.WriteLine ("The row created has a Id = " + returnId);
```

This doesn´t work. I tried also the following variation:

```
        string sql = "INSERT INTO table_name (a, b, c) VALUES (1, 2, 3) RETURNING ID;";
        OracleCommand command = conn.CreateCommand();
        command.CommandText = sql;

        int rowsUpdated = command.ExecuteNonQuery();

        if (rowsUpdated != 1)
            return;

        OracleDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            string id = (string)reader["ID"];
            Console.WriteLine ("The row created has a Id = " + returnId);
        }
```

This this inserts 2 rows into database, and the reader is empty.

So, what´s the correct way to programatically use RETURNING INTO clause to get the created row Id.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the generated id from an inserted row using ExecuteScalar?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1336911/how-to-get-the-generated-id-from-an-inserted-row-using-executescalar)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your returning clause is fine but your C# code is all wrong. You need to use the Parameters property - read here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oracleclient.oraclecommand.parameters%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

e.g.:

```
command.Parameters.Add("returnId", OracleType.Number).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
```

after executing your query check `command.Parameters["returnId"].Value`

Comment: I´m trying to change code, this is a clue, but doesn´t work... OracleType is OracleDbType (int32 or decimal) and I can´t find ParameterDirection.Output...