# How to use the nextval in my query?

Tags: c#, oledbcommand

- displays the following error: ORA-01722: invalid number.
- query result after running the code:

  ```
  INSERT INTO USUARIOS (ID,MATRICULA,NOME,SENHA,NIVEL,MALETA,EMAIL) 
  VALUES ('select id_usuarios.NEXTVAL from dual','TESTE','Frederico','TESTE','1','7000','daerro@erro.com.br')
  ```

protected void btn_incluir_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

```
        OleDbConnection cnx = new OleDbConnection(new AdministradorDAO().conexao);
        cnx.Open();

        string seq = ("select id_usuarios.NEXTVAL from dual");
        OleDbCommand cmdo = new OleDbCommand(seq, cnx);
        cmdo.ExecuteNonQuery();

        //string sqltxt = "INSERT INTO USUARIOS (ID,MATRICULA,NOME,SENHA,NIVEL,MALETA,EMAIL) VALUES (ID_USUARIOS.NextVal,'MATRICULA','NOME','SENHA','NIVEL',MALETA,'EMAIL')";


        string sqltxt = string.Format(
@"INSERT INTO USUARIOS ( ID
      , MATRICULA
      , NOME
      , SENHA
      , NIVEL
      , MALETA
      , EMAIL
  ) VALUES ( '{0}', '{1}', '{2}', '{3}', '{4}', '{5}', '{6}')"
            , seq, txt_matricula.Text, txt_nome.Text, txt_senha.Text
            , DropDownList_nivel.Text, txt_maleta.Text, txt_email.Text);


            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(sqltxt, cnx);

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            txt_matricula.Text = "";
            txt_nome.Text = "";
            txt_senha.Text = "";
            DropDownList_nivel.Text = "";
            txt_maleta.Text = "";
            txt_email.Text = "";
            carregaUsuarios();            

    }
```

Comment: formating data type? example : ID what's data type in table USUARIOS?

Comment: ID = INTEGER. I want a solution to be able to get the last ID in the USUARIOS table, when I fill out the form to add the grid.

Comment: convert seq to from string to int , int.Parse(seq)

Comment: he is not running the first select to retrieve the ID, it is passing the id field to query. Can not a solution to retrieve the last ID from my table to pass the insert query.

Comment: in which "@" utilizade ? have otherwise given passing the values ​​?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the following statement shall raise an error.

```
INSERT INTO USUARIOS (ID
        , MATRICULA
        , NOME
        , SENHA
        , NIVEL
        , MALETA
        , EMAIL
    ) VALUES ( 'select id_usuarios.NEXTVAL from dual'
        , 'TESTE'
        , 'Frederico'
        , 'TESTE'
        , '1'
        , '7000'
        , 'daerro@erro.com.br'
    )
```

The major error in this insert statement is that you try to insert a string into a number field. `ID` as an integer will never accept `'select id_usuarios.NEXTVAL FROM dual'` because you actually try to insert the `'select id_usuarios.NEXTVAL FROM dual'` as being the actual value.

Should you wish to insert the sequence next value into your ID field, try the following:

```
INSERT INTO USUARIOS (ID
        , MATRICULA
        , NOME
        , SENHA
        , NIVEL
        , MALETA
        , EMAIL
    ) ( SELECT id_usuarios.NEXTVAL 
                , 'TESTE'
                , 'Frederico'
                , 'TESTE'
                , 1
                , 7000
                , 'daerro@erro.com.br'
            FROM DUAL
    )
```

Second. both your `NIVEL` and `MALETA` fields seem to be numbers as well, so remove the apostrophes!

Third, it is best to let Oracle handle its sequence itself. The best practice for autoincremental fields using Oracle is to write a `trigger on insert` which will actually select the next sequence value and put it right where it belongs. Plus, notice that if you want to insert a selected value, then you must use an `INSERT SELECT` statemement, not an `INSERT VALUE` statement.

Fourth, using `string.Format` method is really, really, really not a good idea at all as it will let room for [**SQL Injection**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Instead, use have to use command parameters. In addition to it, try to use [**Using Blocks**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/yh598w02.aspx) as they shall dispose any no more required resources when out of scope.

```
using (var cnx = new OleDbConnection(connectionString)) {
    var sql = 
@"insert into usuarios(matricula, nome, sehna, nivel, maleta, email) 
      values (@matricula, @nome, @sehna, @nivel, @maleta, @email)";

    using (var cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, cnx)) {
        cnx.Open();

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@matricula", txt_matricula.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nome", txt_nome.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sehna", txt_senha.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nivel", int.Parse(DropDownList_nivel.Text));
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@maleta", int.Parse(txt_maleta.Text));
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", txt_email.Text);

        try { cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); }
        catch { }
        finally { if(cnx.State == ConnectionState.Open) cnx.Close(); }
    }
}
```

Fifth, it is important to call the right method for the job.

**DbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery**

Method used for `DELETE`, `INSERT` and `UPDATE` statements ONLY.

**DbCommand.ExecuteReader**

Method used for `SELECT` statements with multiple rows and columns.

**DbCommand.ExecuteScalar**

Method used when the expected result or the only important value shall be located in the first column of the first row. Any other rows and columns than the first shall be ignored.

See my answers to these related questions:

- [**ExecuteNonQuery for SELECT sql statement returning no rows**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4269651/162167)
- [**How to get the generated id from an inserted row using ExecuteScalar?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1336911/how-to-get-the-generated-id-from-an-inserted-row-using-executescalar/1343218#1343218)

**EDIT**

> ***I tried giving a hand before a select to retrieve the ID (select id_usuarios.NEXTVAL from dual ) and then retrieve ID already passed the insert***

Here's how I'd go about it.

First, create the trigger on your table.

```
create or replace trigger increment_usuarios_id
        before insert on usuarios
        for each row
    begin
        if :new.id is null then
            select id_usuarios.nextval into :new.id from dual;
        end if;
    end;
```

Then, when inserting into the `usuarios` data table, the `ID` column shall get fed automatically by the `increment_usuarios_id` trigger.

Hence one is now able to insert without taking any special care on the identity.

```
insert into usuarios (
        matricula
        , nome
        , sehna
        , nivel
        , maleta
        , email
    ) values (
        'TESTE'
        , 'Frederico'
        , 'TESTE'
        , 1
        , 7000
        , 'daerror@error.com.br'
    );

commit;
```

You then shall see your new user into the table as expected. If this works, then take the same `insert statement` and make it the value of your `sql` variable within your C# code, not forgetting to replace values with the actual control values from your GUI.

Comment: is now falling in CATCH and with the following error: {"One or more errors occurred during processing of command \ r \ Nora-00936:. phrase not found"}

Comment: Try running the statement directly in your RDBMS client, be it Toad for Oracle or SQL Builder or whatsoever. If this works with no error, then copy and paste your statement to your command text.

Comment: Have you written your `trigger on insert` to increment your sequence?

Comment: I'm not trying to use the oracle sequence (next.val)

Comment: Then if `ID` is defiend as the primary key, you can't haven no `ID` specified. The `insert` herewith provided is a sample based on the use of a `trigger on insert` so that the `ID` column gets assigned automatically by the trigger which responsibility stands within setting the `ID` and inserting the provided values from the command.

Comment: I tried giving a hand before a select to retrieve the ID (select id_usuarios.NEXTVAL from dual ) and then retrieve ID already passed the insert . More unsuccessfully went wrong !

Comment: when I run the following query in toad , it works correctly.

insert into usuarios (
        matricula
        , nome
        , sehna
        , nivel
        , maleta
        , email
    ) values (
        'TESTE'
        , 'Frederico'
        , 'TESTE'
        , 1
        , 7000
        , 'daerror@error.com.br'
    );

Comment: in which "@" utilizade ? have otherwise given passing the values ​​?

Comment: The @ sign in front of a string in C# means that the string should be interpreted as-is, with no escape sequences and such, etc. For further details on `string`, please see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/ms228362.aspx

Answer (score 0):

look this :[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5893837/using-parameters-inserting-data-into-access-database)

```
         OleDbConnection cnx = new OleDbConnection(new AdministradorDAO().conexao);
         cnx.Open();

         string seq = ("select id_usuarios.NEXTVAL from dual");
         OleDbCommand cmdo = new OleDbCommand(seq, cnx);
         int id= (int)cmdo.ExecuteScalar(); 

         using (OleDbCommand cmd = cnx.CreateCommand())
         {
       // create command with placeholders
          cmd.CommandText = 
          "INSERT INTO USUARIOS"+
          "([ID], [MATRICULA],  [NOME], [SENHA], [NIVEL],[MALETA],[EMAIL]) "+
          "VALUES(@id, @ma, @no, @se, @ni,@ma,@em)";

       // add named parameters
       cmd.Parameters.AddRange(new OleDbParameter[]
       {
           new OleDbParameter("@id", id),
           new OleDbParameter("@ma", txt_matricula.Text),
           ...
       };


       cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
  }
```

Replace actual hardcoded parameters in your OleDbCommand with placeholders (prefixed with @),
b) Add instances of OleDbParameter to the DbCommand.Parameters property. Parameter names must match placeholder names.

Comment: now produced the following error: Specified cast is not valid. 
Should I convert the string to cmdo?

Comment: id_usuarios.NEXTVAL , what's data Type ?

Comment: "ID" in my database is integer, I'm using Oracle.

Comment: displays the following error: {"Specified cast is not valid."}

Comment: You need to pass string to varchar2, and numeric to number's.

Comment: help there guys, please!

Comment: What is the value id ?  MessageBox.Show(id.ToString());and give me this value

Comment: What are the other fields Data Type is number ?

Comment: ID = INTEGER, MATRICULA = VARCHAR2, NOME = VARCHAR2, SENHA = VARCHAR2, NIVEL = VARCHAR2, MALETA = INTEGER, EMAIL = CHAR

Answer (score 0):

Will Marcouiller: I see no error in syntax.

```
using (var cnx = new OleDbConnection(new AdministradorDAO().conexao))
{
    var sql = @"insert into usuarios(matricula, nome, senha, nivel, maleta, email) values (@matricula, @nome, @senha, @nivel, @maleta, @email)";

    using (var cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, cnx))
    {
        cnx.Open();

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@matricula", txt_matricula.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nome", txt_nome.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@senha", txt_senha.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nivel", int.Parse(DropDownList_nivel.Text));
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@maleta", int.Parse(txt_maleta.Text));
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", txt_email.Text);

        try { cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); }
        catch { }
        finally { if (cnx.State == ConnectionState.Open) cnx.Close(); }

    }
}
```

Comment: when I run the query directly in the toad , works correctly . insert into actweb.usuarios (matricula, nome, senha, nivel, maleta, email) values ('TESTE', 'Frederico', 'TESTE', 1, 7000, 'daerror@error.com.br');